# Except 1 PHP variable all other data from $_POST are getting

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to pick the data from using POST method, while echo except once rests all shows.

```
<div>
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update User Profile</h5>
      <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      </button>
    </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  <form class="user" method="post">
      <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>">
          </div>
      </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" name="user_email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control form-control-user" name="user_phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>">
          </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" name="password" placeholder="Password">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="charts.php">Back to List</a>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" name="update-user-profile" href="">Update Profile</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<?php

      if(isset($_POST['update-user-profile'])){

        $updateFirstname = $_POST['first_name'];
        $updateLastname = $_POST['last_name'];
        $updateUserEmail = $_POST['user_email'];
        $updateUserPhone = $_POST['user_phone'];
        $newPassword = $_POST['password'];
        $newConfirmPassword = $_POST['confirmPassword'];

            echo $updateFirstname."<br/>";
            echo $updateLastname."<br/>";
            echo $updateUserEmail."<br/>";
            echo $updateUserPhone."<br/>";

      }


  ?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: last_name in C:\wamp64\www\tour-management\user-update.php on line 94

Comment: `name="first_name"` using twice, u are using first_name in last_name field, **second** you are not closing `<form>` also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have not used `<form></form>` tags.

You have used input with name firstname twice, therefore you are not getting the lastname option.

```
<div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>">
      </div>
```

Here in above code I have change first_name to last_name. So if you change it, the whole thing should work.